# Fast Creation of a very large File in Debian Linux

Tags: c, linux, debian

I am currently working on a project that involves transferring a very large file (about 6GB) from one Linux Server to another. The servers run on Debian Squeeze.
In order to achieve my main goal, I initially send the file's name and size to the destination machine, and I create an empty file for storing the data blocks that I progressively receive from the source machine. 
My problem is that the creation of a 6GB file takes too long in my server. To make it more clear I use the following C routine in order to create the new file:

```
void create_file(char* f_name, long long f_size) {
    char* bs, *of, *s_f_size, *count;
    if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            perror("fork() failed.");
            return;
    }
    if(pid == 0) {
        //Call execl
        of = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen("of=") + strlen(f_name) + 1));
        s_f_size = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
        sprintf(s_f_size, "%lld", file_size);
        count = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen("count=") + strlen(s_f_size) + 1));
        strcpy(of, "of=");
        strcat(of, f_name);
        strcpy(count, "count=");
        strcat(count, s_f_size);
        ret = execl("/bin/dd", "dd", "if=/dev/zero", of, "bs=1", count, (char*) 0);
        if(ret < 0) {
            perror("execl() failed");
            free(s_f_size);
            free(of);
            free(count);
            return;
        }else {
            free(s_f_size);
            free(of);
            free(count);
            return;
        }
    }else {
        status = 0;
        wpid = wait(&status);

    }
}
```

I used the Linux dd command because I thought that it would be the quickest way to create an empty 6GB file. However, it takes about 15 minutes to complete. Is there a way to create the empty file faster? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Sincerely,
Nick

Comment: Does it take this long if you run `dd` directly from the command-line?

Comment: Why do you want to create file? If you are sending data sequentially, just keep appending to the file.

Comment: @Oli I cannot run dd directly from the command-line, because the above routine is called from a C server which I implemented.

Comment: Even if it's not sequential, all you have to do is open the file whenever you receive a chunk, seek to the chunk location, and write it there. It'll grow sparsely as needed, and when you've got all the chunks, it won't be sparse anymore.

Comment: @Rohan there is no guarantee that the data will be sent sequentially.

Comment: oh and `bs=1` is how you ask for the worst possible performance, sending bytes from userspace to kernel one at a time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good method for making a huge test file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707058/what-is-a-good-method-for-making-a-huge-test-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First [`creat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/creat.html) the file, then [`lseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html) to the wanted end, and [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html) a dummy byte. Very quick way to create an arbitrary large but [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) file.

---

If you don't want the file to be sparse, then find out the block size of the drive (can be found out using [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) on most POSIX platforms). Create a buffer of that size, and write it to the file until the wanted size.

If the [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) structure doesn't have the `st_blksize` member, then most filesystems have a blocksize of 4 or 8 kB. You can probably make this buffer larger, but not too large. Experiment and benchmark!

Comment: Bu that won't reserve the disk space beforehand, due to its sparseness.  Maybe the OP *wants* to reserve the disk space to avoid running out of space during transmission of the contents.

Comment: Why specifically creat and not open System Call?

Comment: @popanik Because you mentioned creation, so it's the natural system call to just open a file for creation. `open` with the right flags will work too of course.

Comment: Thank you for your help @JoachimPileborg. I will use your answer in my system. I really appreciate your quick and accurate response.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what Joachim Pileborg suggested, you can also use [`posix_fallocate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/posix_fallocate.html) to pre-allocate space for your file.

Comment: I will keep that in mind @Hasturkun. Thank your for your precious help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using kernel v2.6.31+ and if filesystem supports it, consider using `fallocate`:

```
fallocate -l 6GB hugefile
```

[It](http://linuxreviews.org/man/fallocate/) preallocates blocks to a file.

Comment: Yes but, is it significantly faster than dd?

Comment: Yes, it is.  The difference will be more significant as the file size increases.  `time` the two to figure.

Comment: Just seen it and it is quite faster. Thank you very much for your help guys. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Creating large files takes long because there's a lot on the file system the OS has to do.  Only in case of sparse files this can be skipped (see Joachim Pileborg's answer for that).  A sparse file is a file containing "holes" (large chunks of zero bytes).  Such a file does not use as much space as it is large.  Creating such a file beforehand will produce the file with the correct size very fast.

In case you want to reserve the disk space to avoid running out of it before the transmission is complete, a sparse file won't do.  You will have to write at least one byte into each block then to avoid the holes of a sparse file.  I'm not sure this will be faster than simply dump zeros into the file until it has the desired size, as you already do.

Comment: what is the low-level difference between a sparse file and a pre-allocated disk space file? Apart from the danger that my disk will run out of disk space during the transfer of the file, will I encounter any other differences between the use of a sparse file and a pre-allocated file?

Comment: The only other difference I can think of is that everybody who looks at the disk usage of that sparse file will see that it doesn't really use 6GB of space.

Comment: Well, since the system that I am working on is a prototype, I do not really care (at this point) about that. So, I think I will go with the sparse file solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i remember, i've used open system call to create a empty file. Then dump data to file. 
In case of partial data write, keep seek the position and dump from there. If file exists use the file to overwrite the data into it.

With respect to performance this approach was quite good.